# Copy files from Vendor S3 bucket to my using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to copy/transfer files from the Vendor's AWS S3 bucket to my AWS S3 bucket using Lambda. The Lambda will go over all available files in the vendor bucket and transfer all those to my bucket.

The vendor provides a standard way for clients to access files from their AWS Account / S3 bucket. Vendor creates IAM user per client and grants Get object permission on S3 bucket. The vendor doesn't allow any additional changes to their S3 Policy or IAM user permission. With that, my Lambda won't have a role assumed with Get permissions on vendor bucket and Put permission on my bucket.

Can I have Lambda coded to use the IAM user (provided by the vendor) to connect to the Vendor S3 bucket and access files then have another IAM User (in my account which has access to my bucket) connect to my bucket and put objects??? If yes, as there would be two separate S3 connections how to pass the object received from one to another s3 connection?

Comment: There is now S3 copy API that operates on two different credentials.  You'll need to read the object with one credential, then write the object with another.  You could download to the ephemeral storage of the Lambda, then upload from the Lambda, for instance.

Comment: Hi @AnonCoward, thank you for the replay, can you share an example of an S3 Copy API that operates on two diff credentials?

Comment: Sorry, typo, it should say "There is _no_ S3 copy API that operates on two different credentials"

Answer (score 1):

You should **add a Bucket Policy** to your Amazon S3 bucket that permits write access by the IAM User provided by your vendor.

This way, that **one set of credentials** will be able to access their bucket *AND* access your bucket.

This method does not require them to modify permissions on the IAM User.

I also recommend that you set `ACL=BucketOwnerFullControl` as part of the copy, so that the object is 'owned' by the destination account.